# How to access master page public property from a NESTED content page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, master-pages

After exposing a public property in `Top.Master` it can be accessed in any child page that has a master type reference on its page.

How can the same properties be accessed from a nested page?

I tried to cascade the properties down the heirarchy but the child page errors when trying to access it.

I would prefer to access the exposed top.master property directly from the nested content page but am unsure of a good way to do this.

---

**TOP.MASTER**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="Server" />
```

**TOP.MASTER.VB**

```
Partial Public Class TopMaster
  Inherits MasterPage

  Public Property Msg As String
    Get
      Return lblMsg.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      lblMsg.Text = value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

---

**CHILD.MASTER**

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Top.Master" %>
```

**CHILD.MASTER.VB**

```
Master.Msg = "Success"
```

---

**CHILD.PAGE**

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Child.Master" %>
```

**CHILD.PAGE.VB**

```
Master.Master.Msg = "Success"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child.master class you can create a `Msg` property that would proxy the top master `Msg` property

You can add the following code in *child.master.vb*

```
  Public Property Msg As String
    Get
      Return Master.Msg
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      Master.Msg = value
    End Set
  End Property
```

then in your *child.page.vb* you can access this property doing

```
Master.Msg = "Success"
```